# Highcharts: Sudden changes in the height of the plot area over time

Tags: highcharts

I have a live chart with the following settings (somewhat similar):

```
<div id="container" style="height:260px"></div>


Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
          type: 'spline',
          animation: false,
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Live Data'
        },
        accessibility: {
            announceNewData: {
                enabled: true,
                minAnnounceInterval: 5000,
                announcementFormatter: function (allSeries, newSeries, newPoint) {
                    if (newPoint) {
                        return 'New point added. Value: ' + newPoint.y;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            }
        },
        data: {
            csvURL: urlInput,
            enablePolling: true,
            dataRefreshRate: 1
        },
          
      
     
     plotOptions: {
       spline: {
         marker: {
           enabled: false
         }
       }
     },
      xAxis: {
        plotLines: [{value: 0, color: '#ff0000', width: 10, zIndex: 100}],
        type: 'datetime',
        tickInterval: 750, // ms
        tickColor: '#636363',
        tickLength: 6,
        alignTicks: 10,
        minorGridLineWidth: 0,
        minorTickInterval: 1000,
        minorTickColor: '#cccccc',
        minorTicks: true,
        minorTickWidth: 1,
        minorTickLength: 3,
      }, 
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'c1'
        },
        min:-4,
        max:4,
        plotLines: [{value: 0, color: '#b3b3b3', width: 1, zIndex: 5}],
        tickAmount: 5,
        startOnTick: false,
        endOnTick: false,
        tickPixelInterval: 50,
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        tickWidth: 1,

      },
      time: {
        useUTC: false
      },      
    });
```

At first the chart behavior looks like below, everything seems correct:
[image]

After about 30-40 seconds, the behavior of the chart changes and we see the following output! The x-axis constantly changes shape and the height of the drawing area changes. This is despite the fact that illegal or strange values are not injected into the chart, so it cannot be said that the reason for this behavior is bad input values.
[image]

Note : The code above is the approximate equivalent of my code, and the original code causes confusion here due to its special format (due to the template language in flask).

Although it does not help and the code in codepen works correctly, but I have something like this code:
[codepen](https://codepen.io/littledemon/pen/VwqKjMg?editors=1010)

**Update:**
If I make the x labels position fixed using the following code in the xAxis section, the problem will be solved to some extent. But part of the problem that remains is "the location of each x point move back and forward and are not fixed."

```
labels: {
  rotation: -45
},
```

I don't know if there is really a way to keep the x points fixed on the graph.

Comment: With the current xAxis settings that are in the demo you sent, I didn't notice that the labels changed their position. Are you sure that the reason is not the data you fetch using data.csvURL?